# In AWS SAM, the SQS I set as a DQL for a given Lambda is not receiving any message

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-sam

I am experiencing with AWS SAM. When a Lambda function fails I want a message to be sent automatically to a SQS Queue. I think I set up everything correctly but I do not get the expected result.

I extended the AWS SAM hello-world example.

hello_world/app.py

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    raise Exception("Something went wrong")
```

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  gym-tracker-sam

  Sample SAM Template for gym-tracker-sam

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      DeadLetterQueue:
        Type: SQS
        TargetArn: !GetAtt MyDeadLetterQueue.Arn
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  MyDeadLetterQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: hello-world-dql

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Once deployed, I can call the endpoint that triggers the hello-world lambda, it is correctly triggered and I get a failure in the monitoring chart as expected.

[Monitoring of the lambda calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EybUJ.png)

But I get nothing in the SQS queue, monitoring charts are flat.
I checked the Cloudfront Logs for the lambda, they show the error that is thrown in the function, but nothing about a "transfer" to SQS

The DQL seems to be configured correctly as it can be found in the asynchronous invocation tab of the lambda:
[lambda function asynchronous invocation tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRcTp.png)

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the SQS has the resource based policy itself. Have you allowed the Lambda function write to the queue?

Comment: @Mink Yes. The `DeadLetterQueue` property in the template under the function definition, gives the lambda the sqs:SendMessage permission.

Comment: I mean both Lambda execution policy and SQS resource based policy need appropriate permission. The Lambda execution role must have send message, and the queue role must allow send message action from Lambda role https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html